# The general way to show completeness of a theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I have difficulty showing the completeness of a certain theory.
Namely, we know the DLO (dense linear order) without endpoints is complete, but what is the clearest way to show that? Similar variance is DLO with one endpoint, with both side endpoints, etc...

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to QE, back and forth methods work here. You can either show any two countable models are isomorphic and then argue for completeness via Lowenheim-Skolem, or use an EF game to show any two models are elementarily equivalent directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "general way" to show the completeness of an arbitrary theory. (I think this is most likely a provable statement: you should be able to reduce the halting problem to deciding the completeness of a recursively axiomatized theory, although I don't feel confident enough in recursion theory to say that with certainty.)

The *usual* way of proving completeness is via quantifier elimination in a language we understand (with the caveat that we can only expand the language by symbols definable in the theory). For instance, DLO has quantifier elimination in the usual language $<$. DLO with the left endpoint has q.e. once you add a constant symbol for the endpoint, etc.

Once you have quantifier elimination, completeness is typically immediate (it is enough to show that quantifier-free sentences are decided).

Comment: Just to clarify "Once you have quantifier elimination, completeness is immediate": yes for DLO and more generally any theory in a language with no non-trivial quantifier-free sentences. If your language has constant symbols, there will be non-trivial quantifier-free sentences, and you must additionally check that $T$ decides the truth value of all of these. Equivaently, every model of $T$ has the same substructure generated by the constants (up to isomorphism).

Comment: @AlexKruckman: You're right. I did not want to get into the details, but I suppose it is a bit misleading. So I elaborated a bit.